# Entity Framework/MVC. How to prevent an image blob saved in the database is deleted when update current record without selecting a new image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, image, entity-framework, blob

Here's the code to understand my problem:

**CONTROLLER:**

```
[HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Field1,Field2,ect")] ControllerName controllername, HttpPostedFileBase ImageData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ImageData != null && ImageData.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(ImageData.InputStream))
                    {
                        controllername.ImageBLOB_FieldDB = reader.ReadBytes(ImageData.ContentLength);    //imageUrl è un tipo varbinary
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ImageData = controllername.ImageBLOB_FieldDB;
                }

                db.Entry(controllername).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                                validationError.PropertyName,
                                                validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return View(controllername);
    }
```

**VIEW:**

```
   <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageBLOB_FieldDB, htmlAttributes:      new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="col-md-3">Current Image</label>
                @if (Model.ImageBLOB_FieldDB!= null)
            {
                    <img style="height:auto; max-width:200px; width:100%; float: left !important; text-align: left !important; "
                         src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "controllername", new { id = Model.Id })' />
                }
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div id="imageNew" class="hidden">
                    <label class="col-md-3">New Image</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div id="osp">
                            <div id="imagePreview"></div><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="file" id="ImageData" name="ImageData" onchange="fileCheck(this);" />
        </div>
     </div>
```

when I save and do not select a new image, the previous saved is deleted. Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance!

In practice, I can not "keep" in the previous case intake change ... I think this is because the input "ImageData" is not initialized and it is eliminating the previous year.

Answer (score 1):

I solved simply by this code line in the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ImageBLOB_FieldDB);
```